# How do I navigate to privileges link?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm stuck on navigate to privileges link, in old header I can access through the **privilege link** on profile picture mouse over. but now I can not find the link even in my profile page.
How can I go to my privileges ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the *help* link, then click on *Help Center*, then click on *View a full list of privileges you can earn*

[image: help link]

[image: help center link]

[image: priviliges link]

Answer (score 3):

One of the options is to click on the *Badges* link on the page and below the *Ask Question* button you'll have a list which has the *Privileges* link in it.

[image: Privileges]

By default the *Badges* would be selected as you went to that page initially.